# Creating a view in SQL Server by retrieving some specific data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having trouble retrieving to list for every genre, the movies with the maximal rating for that genre. So far I have joined the table that are needed.

```
SELECT 
    movie_title,genre, rating
FROM 
    movie 
JOIN 
    dvd_movie ON movie.movie_id = dvd_movie.movie_id 
JOIN 
    dvd ON dvd_movie.dvd_id = dvd.dvd_id 
JOIN 
    language_audio_dvd ON language_audio_dvd.dvd_id = dvd.dvd_id 
JOIN 
    rating ON rating.rating_id = movie.rating_id 
JOIN  
    genre ON genre.genre_id = movie.genre_id
```

I have the following database diagram.

[image]

How can I create a view that lists for every genre, the movies with the maximal rating for that genre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, here is one of the simpler ways:

```
SELECT movie_title,genre, rating
FROM (
    SELECT  movie_title,
            genre_id,
            rating,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY genre_id 
                             ORDER BY rating, movie_id) AS gRank
    FROM    movie
    JOIN    rating  ON rating.rating_id = movie.rating_id
     ) AS movie
JOIN genre  ON genre.genre_id = movie.genre_id
WHERE gRank = 1
```

This uses a subquery with a ROW_NUMBER function to rank all of the movies within their genre's.  Then in the outer query keeps only those movie rows that were ranked 1 within their genre.

The ROW_NUMBER function adds the extra ORDER BY criteria `movie_id` only to insure that the rankings are both unique and stable.